# lag screws vs through-bolts when cabling to prevent a split at the crotch

Tags: trees, wind-damage

When cabling a tree with two main leads to prevent it from splitting at the crotch, is there any advantage to the tree to using a lag screw rather than a through-bolt, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

I used a through bolt, no cable . You can but threaded rod of any length and the thread pitch is less than the screw pitch of a lag so it is more convenient to adjust the length and tension. I did it on a Chinese or Siberian elm . In a few years when I sold the house ,bark had grown over the nuts and I had forgotten it.

Comment: If you bolt through the codominant leads up above the trunk, up where they are separated by a few feet of space, rather than below where they form a trunk together,  do you just size the rod a foot or two longer so you can back off the nuts to allow for growth and further separation of the leads?  I am looking around town at trees maintained by tree businesses, and all I see are cables, no turnbuckles or devices that would allow for growth and further separation.